# Persistence.xml doesn't exist or can't be accessed

Tags: jpa, persistence, java-ee-8

When run my test, i have problem that my test method can not invoke, in stack trace this caused by

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: persistence.xml doesn't exist or can't be accessed
```

My file located in `/src/main/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml`

My test

```
@Deployment
public static JavaArchive createDeployment() {
    return ShrinkWrap.create (JavaArchive.class)
            .addPackage (PersistanceService.class.getPackage())
            .addPackage(Todo.class.getPackage())
            .addAsResource("persistence.xml", "/META-INF/persistence.xml")
            .addAsManifestResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "beans.xml");
    
}
```

Also if i comment //.addAsResource("persistence.xml", "/META-INF/persistence.xml")
test is completed

if you know what i need to do, please help me, tnx!

[image]

Comment: with addAsResource you are telling it to look for "persistence.xml" and put it in the jar under "/META-INF/persistence.xml" but shrink-wrap can't find persistence.xml. You'll have to check how it can find your /src/main/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml file from where ever it is running - likely just "/META-INF/persistence.xml" though.

Comment: if i change name to /.addAsResource("/META-INF/persistence.xml", "/META-INF/persistence.xml") it also did not work! and "/src/main/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml: also did not work

Comment: Solve problem, in future will be read documentation! 
file persistence.xml must have path  src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/persistence.xml  
"WEB-INF" not META, in this case everything work well